# gerrit didn't work. I still can bypass reviewer

Tags: git, apache, git-push, gerrit

When I use `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch_name`, it works normally. But I use `git push origin HEAD:branch_name`, it can bypass reviewer and push the code into server directly. It's weird! It shall show: *prohibited by [gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/)*. Can anybody else help me??

My Apache2 *httpd.conf* is shown as below

```
<VirtualHost *>  
  ServerName localhost 
  ProxyRequests Off  
  ProxyVia Off  
  ProxyPreserveHost On  

  <Proxy *>  
        Order deny,allow  
        Allow from all  
  </Proxy>  

  <Location /login/>  
     AuthType Basic  
     AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"  
     AuthBasicProvider file  
     AuthUserFile /home/kk/gerrit/server/etc/passwords  
     Require valid-user  
  </Location>  

  ProxyPass / http://10.10.68.224:9091/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.68.224:9091/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gerrit documentation](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4.2/user-upload.html#bypass_review) describes how the the review process may be by-passed by the project owner. Possible to restrict this permission, see the Push category in the [access control section](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4.2/access-control.html).